# iOS: Querying all stored login details from keychain

Tags: ios, keychain

I have an iOS app that can connect to any number of distinct services and each of those services have a number of information (such as Service name, URL, Login Name, Password etc).

I have looked at the keychain functions and the wrapper functions (Apple's [GenericKeychain](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GenericKeychain/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007797-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) sample)
The examples I have seen seem show storing and retrieving a single dictionary object for a key.

The flow in my application is
1. Application starts
2. Retrieve all the stored login information (currently I am using NSUserDefaults as a stopgap)
3. Construct a view with each of the services found using the stored logins 
4. User selects one of the services (or can add a new service) and connects into it

So my question is, How do you go about querying all the stored logins?

Is it a good idea to create a keychain for service names and then after retrieving the saved services, use that as a key to retrieve the associated information (such as the account URL, account Password ?)